# iterating through a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df

```
name  e_count   e_start   e_end

aaaa   3       13,14,15,  18,20,25,

bbbb   2       90,94,      100,102,
```

The field `e_count` described the number of elements in `e_start` and `e_end`. I want to make a new  data frame that adds a column `e_end-e_start`. For example

```
name  e_count   e_start   e_end     e_end-e_start

aaaa   3       13,14,15,  18,20,25,  5,6,10,

bbbb   2       90,94,      100,102,   10,8,
```

I tried the following :

```
df['e_end-e_start'] = ""
new_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
new_frame['e_end-e_start'] = ""
new_frame_idx = -1
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
            new_frame_idx = new_frame_idx + 1
            new_row = df.ix[idx]
            new_frame = new_frame.append(new_row,ignore_index = True)      
            df.ix[idx,'e_end-e_start'] =df.ix[idx,'e_end']-df.ix[idx,'target_end']
            new_frame.ix[new_frame_idx,'e_end-e_start'] =df.ix[idx,'e_end-e_start'] =df.ix[idx,'e_end']-df.ix[idx,'target_end']
print new_frame
```

But I get an error. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll get much better performance storing your data as ints instead
of a numeric strings seperated by commas. A flat, long format such as

```
In [73]: df
Out[73]: 
   name  e_start  e_end
0  aaaa       13     18
0  aaaa       14     20
0  aaaa       15     25
1   bbb       90    100
1   bbb       94    102
```

makes computation much easier. Here is how you can convert your DataFrame to the
flat format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'e_count': [3, 2],
                   'e_end': ['18,20,25,', '100,102,'],
                   'e_start': ['13,14,15,', '90,94,'],
                   'name': ['aaaa', 'bbb']})

dfs = []
for col in ['e_start', 'e_end']:
    tmp = df[col].str.strip(',').str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)
    tmp = tmp.stack()
    tmp.index = tmp.index.droplevel(-1)
    tmp.name = col
    tmp = tmp.astype(int)
    dfs.append(tmp)

df = pd.concat([df[['name']]]+dfs, axis=1)
```

Then, to compute the differences, you could use

```
df['diff'] = df['e_end'] - df['e_start']
```

To convert back to the comma separated strings,

```
In [76]: df.groupby('name').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
Out[76]: 
       e_start     e_end    diff
name                            
aaaa  13,14,15  18,20,25  5,6,10
bbb      90,94   100,102    10,8
```

Comment: My original data frame had other columns like 'feature' : ['ccc','ccc'] and so on  (I had omitted this for simplicity in my original question). If I use df = pd.concat([df[['name']]]+dfs, axis=1), the other columns do not appear. Can you tell me how I can get all the columns of the original dataframe. I prefer the final table to be in the format   name  feature e_start  e_end
0  aaaa    ccc   13     18
0  aaaa    ccc  14     20
0  aaaa    ccc  15     25
1   bbb     ccc 90    100
1   bbb     ccc  94    102